# Regular expression doesn't work

Tags: regex

I have this simple line of code using regular expressions where I want to substitute pieces of strings with empty space:

```
newAddress = myAddress.replace(/^.*?(ramp|arterial|majorroad|street &|highway &|highway|street|street &|street & highway|arterial & street|street & arterial|majorroad &|majorroad & ramp|ramp & majorroad|major road|highway & majorroad)\,/gi, '');
```

but having in a variable this:

```
Highway & Contrada Torremuzza, 95121 Catania CT
```

why it didn't removed the "highway &" part?

Comment: It successfully matches `highway &` with that regex, but the `,` at the end can't be matched, so stops it: http://regex101.com/r/oW5bX6

Comment: @OnlineCop actually that's the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just solved by myself with:

```
newAddress = myAddress.replace(/^.*?ramp|arterial|majorroad|street|highway| &|\,/gi, '');
```

shorter and more efficient...so at least it will match the word plus the &

Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 1):

It is trying to match a comma as well, you need to make the comma optional or remove it in this case. Also unless you want to remove the preceding text as well remove the beginning of string `^` anchor and `.*?`

```
newAddress = myAddress.replace(/(ramp|arterial|majorroad|street &|highway &|highway|street|street &|street & highway|arterial & street|street & arterial|majorroad &|majorroad & ramp|ramp & majorroad|major road|highway & majorroad)/gi, '');
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you need neither the `.*` nor the comma. The `.*` will cause you to replace everything that precedes your string.

Try just this:

```
(ramp|arterial|majorroad|street &|highway &|highway|street|street &|street & highway|arterial & street|street & arterial|majorroad &|majorroad & ramp|ramp & majorroad|major road|highway & majorroad)
```

Or, if you're in a mood for fancy optimizations:

```
(?:majorroad & )?ramp|(?:major r|(?:(?:ramp|highway) & )?majorr)oad|(?:highway|majorroad|street) &|(?:arterial & )?street|(?:street & )?(?:arterial|highway)
```

Just kidding. In theory this is more efficient, but it's harder to maintain.